# Asyncio file reading json

Tags: python, json, python-asyncio

I am trying to read a `json` file in an **async function**.

I managed to find this code that works, but is rather clunky in the sense that it requires three extra parts for the file read:

1. import `aiofiles`
2. read the file
3. convert file to dict

```py
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import json


async def main():
    # Read the contents of the json file.
    async with aiofiles.open('rhydon.json', mode='r') as f:
        contents = await f.read()

    # Load it into a dictionary and create a list of moves.
    pokemon = json.loads(contents)
    name = pokemon['name']
    moves = [move['move']['name'] for move in pokemon['moves']]

    # Open a new file to write the list of moves into.
    async with aiofiles.open(f'{name}_moves.txt', mode='w') as f:
        await f.write('\n'.join(moves))


asyncio.run(main())
```

Ideally, i would like to use just the `asyncio` module alone, so was wondering if this is achievable in that module or if it is necessary to use `aiofiles` or if i have missed a better method altogether ?

Answer (score 1):

asyncio does not support asynchronous file operations, you can see [the asyncio wiki](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem) for further explanation

aiofiles allows you to read files asynchronously by delegating their operations to a separate thread pool

Comment: so effectively delegating to the main() eventloop....  and `aiofiles` is the only method...  comment appreciated.